# PHP, MYSQL UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Не работает перебор значения в циклах `for`, `foreach`.

Конкретнее после удаления строки из таблицы, обновить столбец с `id`. Т.е. например мы имеем таблицу где в ней есть столбец `id` со значениями `1, 2, 3 ...` послед удаления строки например `2` столбец с `id` принимает значения `1, 3...`. Мне нужно осуществить обновление столбца `id` в соответствии количество строк, что бы стало `id: 1, 2 ...`.

Логика такая удалить значение с бд и после обновить столбец с `ID`.

```
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM test WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'");
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM test");
while($idCheck[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($id)) {
    #echo $idCheck["id"]."\n";
}

echo count($idCheck);
for($i = 0; $i < count($idCheck); $i++) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE test SET id=".$i);
}
```

получил массив со значениями в поле `id` он соответствует бд. Но в переборе в цикле значений в обновление бд вписывает общее значение строк после удаления . Т.е вместо `1, 2, 3 ...` записывает `2, 2, 2...`

Comment: забавно будет, если вам в качестве `$_GET['id']` кто-то передаст `0' or id in (select id from test)#` не правда ли?

Comment: забавно, вопрос не в этом

Comment: у вас в `$rows` просто число строк. То есть если у вас в таблице после удаление осталось 350 строк. вернется 350. И далее вы делаете 350 апдейтов где `id= 350`. вы ведь не извлекаете конкретные id из таблицы, а только используете их общее значение.

Comment: нет, после удаления будет 349 строк, и id будет 349 .. 351

Comment: исходную задачу объясните. вы апдейтите всю таблицу последним запросом

Comment: во втором вашем решении тоже абсурд какой-то написан.

Comment: извиняюсь в последнем решении. Сейчас отредактирую его

Comment: все же напишите, что и как вы хотите обновить в таблице. ваш код этого совершенно не проясняет. особенно если учесть что в апдейтах нет части `set ..`

Comment: @teran я обновил описание, надеюсь так будет понятнее

Answer (score 3):

**Другой вариант тоже не работает** - тут стоит включить отображение ошибок на экран, потому что исходя из "конструкции"

```
foreach ($idCheck as $key => $value) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE test WHERE id='".$value[$key]."'");
}
```

вряд-ли существует индекс `$value[$key]` вообще

Comment: Существует, выдача общего числа строк.

Comment: @СтаниславФарфудинов не придумывайте, `$value` это число/

Answer (score 1):

```
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM test WHERE id=".$_GET['id']);
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM test");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($id);
$fields = mysql_num_fields($id);
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE test WHERE id = ".$i);
}
```

Comment: Вы меняете в цикле переменную $i, а подставляете постоянную $rows.

Comment: не работает, посмотрите мою обновление в посте,  как вы написали я уже делал

Comment: Мало исходных данных. Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: что делает ваш код? Обновиь значения столбца бд ID после удаления из бд строки

Comment: "UPDATE test WHERE id = ".$i
эта строка ничего не делает

Comment: я знаю, это ваш код

Comment: нет это ваш код "UPDATE test WHERE id = '".$rows[i]."'"

Answer (score 0):

Если не брать во внимание в целом использование get-запроса для измеения данных, использование устаревшего расширения для работы с БД, отсутствие какой-либо проверки на валидность данных и защиты от инъекций, и самое главное непонятность, зачем это все надо, то задачу надо решать не через циклы на стороне пхп.

у вас есть цепочка идентификаторов 1 2  3 4 5. Вы удаляете 3, получаете 1 2 4 5. Далее вместо циклов по перебору нужно выполнить только один запрос на апдейт записей 4 и 5 уменьшив их на 1.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
mysql_query("delete from test where id = $id");
mysql_query("update test set id = id - 1 where id > $id") ;
```

в своих попытках решения `UPDATE test SET id=$i`  у вас нет условия `where`, так что вы данным значением обновляете всю таблицу целиком. вот и остаются значения только последней итерации цикла.

Comment: спасибо, работает. Оказывается все так просто.

Comment: @space_is_fun тогда ткните галку у вопроса